# Declaration of structures in multiple files

Tags: c, structure, declaration

If I include the declaration of the *part* structure(for example) into two different files,
will *part* variables in one file be of the same type as *part* variables in the other file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they're of the same type if the declarations are structurally the same. If this weren't true, it wouldn't be possible to call library functions that use structure parameters, since the caller and callee are in different files.

The declarations don't have to be literally the same. As long as they specify the same types in the same order, things like member names and the name of the struct type don't have to match. So if you do:

file1.c:

```
struct {
    int i;
    char c;
} var1;
```

and in file2.c:

```
typedef struct newstruct {
    int v1;
    char v2;
} newstruct_t;
newstruct_t var2;
```

then `var1` and `var2` are of the same type.

The full details are a bit more complex, but this is a useful approximation.

However, programming like this will be confusing. If you intend to share a type between files, you should put the declaration in a header file, and `#include` it in all the source files that use it.

Comment: Right.  To make sure that you get the same declaration in both files, it is good practice to put your `struct` declaration in a header file and include this from both your `.c` files.

Comment: @nickie I thought that's what he meant when he said _include the declaration_, but now I see that he could have meant putting the declarations directly into the source files, not using `#include`.

Comment: what if one declaration contains tag and the other one does not.will they still be of same type?

Comment: @Barmar I still could not understand what exactly was meant by ` If this weren't true, it wouldn't be possible to call library functions that use structure parameters, since the caller and callee are in different files.` Please shed some light for me

Comment: @bubble You write a program that calls `stat()`, and it takes a `struct stat*` argument. Your program is in a different source file than the `stat()` library function. If your `stat` structure weren't the same as the library's `stat` structure, you wouldn't be able to call the function, since the argument wouldn't be compatible.